# Lines Graph are rendering as straight Lines in AM Charts

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts

I am trying to draw Line Graph but these are rendering as a straight line in the bottom of graph area.I have added columns graphs too in it. they are showing properly but Lines Graph are not showing correct just a straight line. I have added the screenshot in the end. Please help.

This is my graph header

```
var header_graph = [{"balloonText":"[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                       "fillAlphas":"1",
                       "id":"ProductA",
                       "title":"Produc A ",
                       "type":"SmoothedLine",
                       "valueField":"column2"}];
```

This is my graph data values

```
var data_graph  = [{"category":"Jan",  
                    "column1":"85", "column2":"24", "column3":"343", 
                    "column4":"85",  "column5":"31", "column6":"267", 
                    "column7":"85",  "column8":"19", "column9":"439"},......]
```

This is the whole script to generate the chart

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "depth3D": 2,
    "startDuration": 1,
    "theme": "light",
    "precision": 2,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "title": "",
        "position": "left",
        "autoGridCount": false,
    }, {
        "id": "v2",
        "title": "",
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "position": "right",
        "autoGridCount": false
    }],
    "graphs": header_graph ,
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph": "column2",
        "oppositeAxis": false,
        "offset": 30,
        "scrollbarHeight": 50,
        "backgroundAlpha": 0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha": 0,
        "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
        "autoGridCount": true,
        "color": "#AAAAAA"
    },
    "chartCursor": {
        "pan": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
    },
    "categoryField": "category",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": false,
        "dashLength": 1,
        "minorGridEnabled": true,
        "gridPosition": "start"
    },
    "legend": {
        "useGraphSettings": true,
        "position": "bottom"
    },
    "balloon": {
        "borderThickness": 1,
        "shadowAlpha": 0
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "dataProvider":  data_graph

});
```

[image: AMCharts Lines Graph]

Answer (score 0):

The chart is drawing your line at scale with respect to your chart's range of values and it looks like your values for the line are very small compared to the rest of your columns. It will look like a straight line near the bottom as a result of this.

You can use a `valueScrollbar` and let your users zoom in on the valueAxis/Y-axis so they can see the line better. It takes the same properties as a [`chartScrollbar`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartScrollbar) as you can see in [this demo from AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/zoomable-value-axis/):

```
  "valueScrollbar": {
    "autoGridCount": true,
    "color": "#000000",
    "scrollbarHeight": 50
  },
```

Outside of that or making your valueAxis [`maximum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#maximum) smaller, there's not much else you can do.

(Off topic, you should make your values numbers, not strings.)

**Edit**

You can dynamically set the chart's maximum and minimum using [addInitHandler](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#addInitHandler) to have the chart determine these value upon chart initialization like so:

```
//get the maximum and minimum values from the dataProvider
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  var maximum = Number.MIN_VALUE;
  var minimum = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  chart.dataProvider.forEach(function(data) {
    //for each dataProvider element, check the properties that correspond to the chart graphs' valueFields.
    chart.graphs.forEach(function(graph) {
      if (data[graph.valueField] != null) {
        maximum = Math.max(maximum, data[graph.valueField]);
        minimum = Math.min(minimum, data[graph.valueField]);
      }
    });
  });
  chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = maximum;
  chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = minimum;
  chart.valueAxes[0].strictMinMax = true;
}, ["serial"]);
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9d1d17a30a7288c144b4278a8d046ce7?editors=0010)

Comment: Okay let me try this. Yes you are right but I am not sure how long would maximum value axis  go

Comment: From 2000 to 2500, its just a waste of space, if there is no data in this range how can we omit this range and lets keep it to 2000 only

Comment: Set the maximum in the valueAxis. Depending on how your chart is set up, you can do this dynamically in JavaScript prior to the chart creation, or set up your own code to run upon chart initialization through [addInitHandler](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#addInitHandler) and dynamically set your minimumx and maximums. I updated my answer with some code that demonstrates how to do this.